# get current tabIndex value for document with javascript

Tags: javascript, tabindex

I have a custom drop down box I have made and focus can be brought into with the `tab` key automatically, but I can not pass focus to the next element in line...how do I do this?

I was thinking getting the current value of what the current 'tabIndex' is and setting focus to the next in line, any other way? Using mootools btw

Comment: basically how do i get/set the browsers tabIndex, ive tried document and window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old questions, let me share how I solved the problem.

I stashed a text input behind my custom control that actually receives the focus. This way I use it not also to catch text to search the dropdown.